# Pthreads in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a simple program below where it prints the thread id of each thread created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREAD 5

void *runner(void *param);

int main()
{
     int i;
     pthread_t tid[NUM_THREAD];

     for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++){
         pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, runner, NULL);
         printf("%u\n", (unsigned int) pthread_self());
     }

//   for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
//       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}

void *runner(void *param)
{
    /* do some work */

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The code is running fine and giving me the right output.

```
1527895872
1527895872 
1527895872
1527895872
1527895872
```

My question is why are the thread ids the same?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to print `tid[i]`

Answer (score 5):

Because you are printing the thread id of `main()`, instead of the thread itself. You need to move the `printf()` to the code that runs as a thread i.e. `runner()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREAD 5

void *runner(void *param);

int main()
{
     int i;
     pthread_t tid[NUM_THREAD];

     for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++){
         pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, runner, NULL);
         // printf("%u\n", (unsigned int) pthread_self()); // <----- from here
     }

//   for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
//       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}

void *runner(void *param)
{
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned int) pthread_self()); // <-------- to here

    /* do some work */

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is printing the id of the calling thread - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html - this is the same thread each time in the loop;

Perhaps the `printf` should be moved to `runner`

Comment: Note that if you put the `printf` inside of `runner` the output thread ids won't necessarily be printed in the order that they were created.  You would have to do extra work to synchronize the thread output.